# UI Bootstrap Modal promise and controller scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-modal

I'm new to AngularJS and using UI Bootstrap in a project. I want to mark an *I've read the T&Cs* checkbox as checked once the modal (containing the T&Cs text) is closed (but not when the modal is dismissed).

I've adapted the general example at https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ but having issues updating the scope / view with the value of $scope.accept_terms.

I have the modal opening / closing fine, but the checkbox always remains unchecked.

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="user_details_termsConditions"
               name="user_details[termsConditions]"
               required="required" ng-checked="accept_terms" />
        <label for="user_details_termsConditions" >I agree to the <a href="" ng-click="$ctrl.open('', '.modal-container')">terms and conditions</a></label>                 
    </div>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($uibModal, $log, $document, $scope) {
  var $ctrl = this;

  $ctrl.animationsEnabled = true;

  $ctrl.open = function (size, parentSelector) {
    var parentElem = parentSelector ?
    angular.element($document[0].querySelector('.container ' + parentSelector)) : undefined;

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $ctrl.animationsEnabled,
      ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
      ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      controllerAs: '$ctrl',
      size: size,
      appendTo: parentElem
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (result) {
        $scope.accept_terms = result;
        $log.info('accept_terms = ' + $scope.accept_terms);
        // prints accept_terms = 1
    }, function () {

    });

  };
});

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($uibModalInstance) {
  var $ctrl = this;

  $ctrl.ok = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.close(true);
  };
});
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The input element needs an [ng-model directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D)

Comment: Thank-you, that did the trick! I got rid of ng-checked and replaced with ng-model :-).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was a simple matter of using ng-model on the checkbox instead of ng-checked:

Controller:

```
modalInstance.result.then(function (result) {
    $scope.accept_terms = true;
}, function () {

});
```

Markup:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="user_details_termsConditions"
       name="user_details[termsConditions]" required="required"
       ng-model="accept_terms" value="1" />
```